# Android Spinner - Move option left to right

Tags: android

[image: Current spinner look]

Hello, above is what my current spinner looks like.

I would like to change a few small things and need your help:

1. Move app Icon from left to right, so that "Support me" is on the left, and Icon is on the far right.
2. Move the circle items from the right to the left. So I'll have a circle, and then the text. For example (circle, "Rate me").
3. I would like to set focus by default on the "rate me" option, so that when I start the spinner it will be selected. I want the inner circle to be in green, aka highlighted.

Below is the source code:

```
String[] items = new String[] { "Rate me", "Cancel", "Exit" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Support me")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    if (which == 0) {
                        rate();
                    }
                    if (which == 2) {
                        finish();
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).create().show();
```

Thanks for your help, it's very important to a newbie like me.

UPDATE: Here's what I want it to like like:
[image]

Notice the default highlight effect on the first option. I want to create that effect exactly.

Comment: create custom adapter for spinner

Comment: can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create adapter like this way:

```
package com.example.test_all;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView List;
    String a[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        List.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this));
    }

    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context con) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return a.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // return product_id1.size();
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // return product_id1.get(position).hashCode();
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ListContent holder;
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
                holder = new ListContent();

                holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.rad = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);

                // holder.total_rate.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener1);

                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {

                holder = (ListContent) v.getTag();
            }

            holder.name.setText("" + a[position]);

            return v;
        }
    }

    static class ListContent {

        TextView name;
        RadioButton rad;

    }
}
```

custom.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

for more detail check this [blog](http://flowovertop.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-listview-with-radio-button-only.html)

[this link](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/multi-selection-listview-android-with.html) help you to manage radiobutton selection(Here is code of checkbox take idea from that code & manage your selection)

Comment: here is sample how Move option left to right. in my code i have used Listview. So, instead of listview use spinner.